# C syntax: character combinations valid in any context

Tags: c, syntax, grammar

Here's a formal grammar brain teaser (maybe :P)

I'm fairly certain there is no context where the character sequence `=>` may appear in a valid C program (except obviously within a string). However, I'm unable to prove this to myself. Can you either:

- Describe a method that I can use for an arbitrary character sequence to determine whether it is possible in a valid C program (outside a string/comment). Better solutions require less intuition.
- Point out a program that does this. I have a weak gut feeling this could be undecidable but it'd be great if I was wrong.

To get your minds working, other combos I've been thinking about:

`:-` (b ? 1:-1), `!?` don't think so, `?!` (b ?!x:y), `<<<` don't think so.

**If anyone cares**: I'm interested because I'm creating a little custom C pre-processor for personal use and was hoping to not have to parse any C for it. In the end I will probably just have my tokens start with `$` or maybe a backquote but I still found this question interesting enough to post.

**Edit:** It was quickly pointed out that header names have almost no restrictions so let me amend that I'm particularly interested in non-pre-processor code, alternatively, we could consider characters within the `<>` of `#include <...>` as a string literal.

**Re-edit:** I guess macros/pre-processor directives beat this question any which way I ask it :P but if anyone can answer the question for *pure* (read: non-macro'd) C code, I think it's an interesting one.

Comment: "Point out a program that does this." - a C compiler, perhaps?

Comment: I think OP is asking about a source program using `=>` outside of literals

Comment: @Basile is correct, C compiler will tell me if a source is valid but not whether `=>` can appear in _some_ valid source.

Comment: You could use in practice `#{` and `}#` and `$` like in [MELT macro-strings](http://gcc-melt.org/tutomeltlang.html) - i.e. for its `code_chunk`-s.

Comment: I suppose `!??-0` is a valid expression. See [trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C). Although I did not find anything for `=>` or `<<<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to all the other quibbles, there are a variety of cases involving macros.

The arguments to a macro expansion don't need to be syntactically correct, although of course they would need to be syntactically correct in the context of their expansion. But then, they might never be expanded:

```
#include <errno.h>

#define S_(a) #a
#define _(a,cosmetic,c) [a]=#a" - "S_(c)
const char* err_names[] = {
  _(EAGAIN,  =>,Resource temporarily unavailable),
  _(EINTR,   =>,Interrupted system call),
  _(ENOENT,  =>,No such file or directory),
  _(ENOTDIR, =>,Not a directory),
  _(EPERM,   =>,Operation not permitted),
  _(ESRCH,   =>,No such process),
};
#undef _

const int nerr = sizeof(err_names)/sizeof(err_names[0]);
```

Or, they could be used but in stringified form:

```
#define _(a,b,c) [a]=#a" "S_(b)" "S_(c)
```

---

Note: Why `#a` but `S_(c)`? Because `EAGAIN` and friends are macros, not constants, and in this case we *don't* want them to be expanded before stringification.

Comment: IMO this is the only good answer because in this case they are not clearly in a literal/comment and one cannot know whether they will be turned into literals or not used or what.

Comment: @Luis: With respect to your re-edit, (1) I think that your analysis is correct if you exclude strings, comments, and *all* preprocessor directives. (2) However, the last is not "pure" C. It's not C at all. Like it or not, the preprocessor and preprocessor macros are an *essential* part of C; you cannot abstract them away from the language without crippling it. All relevant standards -- standard C, Posix, ... -- insist on macros. And there's no obvious way to split a project into multiple compilation units without the preprocessor.

Comment: no for sure, that's certainly true, which is why it's elaborated. At this point it's 100% an academic exercise :P

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <abc=>
```

is valid in a C program. The text inside the `<...>` can be any member of the source character set except a newline and `>`.

This means that most character sequences, including `!?` and `<<<`, could theoretically appear.

Comment: Brilliant, even if we know that should never happen *in practice* !

Comment: Well then how about `#define NOT_IN_USE =>`?

Comment: damn, good catch, I'm still curious for the non-pre-processor directive case though!

Answer (score 0):

```
/*=>*/  
//=>  
"=>"
'=>'
```

Comment: In the future, please try to provide some explanation of your answer in addition to code